# Extending Phalcon's Flash service- where should I place my class

Tags: php, class, phalcon

I am new to Phalcon and MVC and I want to use the Flash service (is service the correct word here?) to display messages on my view.

The HTML that the flash service produces is not going to work with my template. I am assuming that I have to create my own class and extend it (or implement the interface- not sure which one here) and implement my own methods that return the correct html.

How would I go about this? Do I create a new Class and so something like below:

```
$di->set('flash', function(){
  $flash = MyCustomerFlash(array(
    'error'   => 'alert alert-danger',
    'success' => 'alert alert-success',
    'notice'  => 'alert alert-info',
  ));
  $flash->setAutomaticHtml(false);
  return $flash;
});
```

If so, what folder would my class best go in? Is it an extension/helper or something different?

Thanks!

Comment: may be useful: [How is it possible to output Phalcon\Flash\Direct messages?](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/278). In your view just get the messages and display them any way you wish. $this->flash->getMessages();